# Understanding assembly loop

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

I am having trouble understanding how this code knows when to stop looping. I am supposed to figure out what values are put into %edi. But I can't figure out how many times it loops.

```
0x40106e      movl   $0x2b,0xffffffdc(%ebp)
0x401075      movl   $0x31,0xffffffe4(%ebp)
0x40107c      movl   $0x74,0xffffffec(%ebp)
0x401083      movl   $0x19,0xffffffe8(%ebp)
0x40108a      movl   $0x7,0xffffffd8(%ebp)
0x401091      movl   $0x14,0xffffffe0(%ebp)
0x401098      mov    $0xdead,%edi
0x40109d      mov    $0x2,%ecx
0x4010a2      mov    %ecx,%esi
0x4010a4      mov    $0x3,%ecx
0x4010a9      mov    $0x2,%ebx
0x4010ae      sub    %esi,%ebx
0x4010b0      imul   $0xc,%ebx,%ebx
0x4010b3      mov    $0x3,%edx
0x4010b8      sub    %ecx,%edx
0x4010ba      lea    0xffffffd8(%ebp),%eax
0x4010bd      lea    (%ebx,%edx,4),%ebx
0x4010c0      add    %ebx,%eax
0x4010c2      mov    (%eax),%edi
0x4010c4      loop   0x4010a9
0x4010c6      mov    %esi,%ecx
0x4010c8      loop   0x4010a2
0x4010ca      mov    $0xbeef,%edi
```

edit: Edit: I now understand the looping logic. However I am having a hard time following all the values getting moved around. I am stuck here `lea 0xffffffd8(%ebp),%eax`
How do I know what %ebp is?

Comment: How about asking this on [RE.SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) instead?

Comment: Stands a better chance of being answered over on http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I updated my question to address your additional question, but you really shouldn't edit in new questions like that.  Just ask a new questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `loop` instruction decrements `ecx` and then, if it's not zero, jumps to the specified location.  The instruction before the outer loop puts `2` in `ecx` and the instruction just before the inner loop puts `3` in `ecx`, so the outer loop will be executed twice and the inner loop three times.

Note that the only instructions in the outer loop (other than the initialization of `ecx` for the inner loop) are `mov %ecx, %esi` and `mov %esi, %ecx` - `esi` is being used to save the outer loop's counter while the inner loop runs.

Edit regarding your new question (you really should ask a new one instead of editing this one):

It doesn't matter what `ebp` is since it's never modified or accessed except to get at the variables saved at the beginning of the function.  It's just being used as a base pointer, and it's always going to be the same.